# Hahn Banach extension of the following functional.

Tags: functional-analysis

> The norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined as follows: $$ \| (x,y) \|=|x|+|y|. $$ Now let $$X=:\{ (x,x):\ x\in \mathbb{R}\}$$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2. $ Let $ f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x,y)=3x,\ \forall (x,y)\in X.$ Let $g$ be an extension of $f$ defined as $g(x,y)=\alpha x+\beta y,\ \forall (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$. Then what is the value of $\alpha $ and $\beta.$

Since, $g$ is an extension of $f$, so for every $(x,y)\in X$, 
\begin{align*}
g(x,y)& =f(x,y)=3x\\
\implies \alpha x+\beta y&=3x\\
\implies \alpha x+\beta x& =3x \tag{$x=y$ on $X$}\\
\implies \alpha +\beta &=3
\end{align*}
Now the Hahn Banach extension preserves the norm of the functional, i.e. $\|g\|=\|f\|$. The norm of $f$ is, 
\begin{align*}
\|f\| & = \sup\left\lbrace \frac{|f(x,x)|}{\|(x,x)\|}:\ (x,x)\neq 0  \right\rbrace \\
      & = \sup\left\lbrace \frac{|3x|}{|x|+|x|}:\ x\neq 0  \right\rbrace\\
      & = \sup\left\lbrace \frac{3}{2}:\ x\neq 0  \right\rbrace\\
      & = \frac{3}{2}
\end{align*}
Now $\|g\|=\|f\|=\frac{3}{2}$
\begin{align*}
\|g\| & = \sup\left\lbrace \frac{|g(x,y)|}{\|(x,y)\|}:\ \|(x,y)\|\neq 0 \right\rbrace\\
      & =  \sup\left\lbrace \frac{|\alpha x+\beta y|}{\|(x,y)\|}:\ \|(x,y)\|\neq 0 \right\rbrace\\
& =  \sup\left\lbrace \frac{|(3-\beta) x+\beta y|}{\|(x,y)\|}:\ \|(x,y)\|\neq 0 \right\rbrace\\
& =  \sup\left\lbrace \frac{|3x+\beta(y-x)|}{|x|+|y|}:\ \|(x,y)\|\neq 0 \right\rbrace\\
\end{align*}
After that I stuck. Can anyone help me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that
$$|g(x,y)|\leq\frac{1}{2}\max\{|\alpha|,|\beta|\}\|(x,y)\|.$$
Then try to show that this is a tight bound, i.e. find a $(x,y)$ which gives you equality. By showing this, you will get $\|g\|=\frac{1}{2}\max\{|\alpha|,|\beta|\}$. Finally use what you have shown already to determine $\alpha,\beta$.

Comment: $|g(x,y)| = |\alpha x + \beta y| \leq \max\{|\alpha|,|\beta|\}(|x|+|y|)$. Where does the $\frac{1}{2}$ come from?
(eg, $||(1,0)|| = 1$, and $||g(1,0)|| = |\alpha|$)